# Using regex replacement in Sublime 3

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3, regexp-replace

I am trying to use replace in Sublime using regular expressions but I'm stuck. I tried various combinations but don't seem to be getting there.

This is the input and my desired output:

Input: `N_BBP_c_46137_n`

Output : `BBP`

I tried combinations of:

```
[^BBP]+\b
\*BBP*+\g
```

But none of the above (and many others) don't seem to work.

Comment: If you already know `BBP`, why do you want to extract it?

Comment: just want that entire long name such as N_BBP_* to be replaced by only BBP; I have to do this for a very large number of such data

Comment: `(N_)[^_]*(_c_46137_n)` -> `${1}some new value$2`?

Comment: Or `\bN_(BBP)_\S*` and replace with group 1 `$1`

Comment: amazing! this works; now just to confirm, I can replace the number 46137 with \d since it'll be different for every case; also the _n and all will be different? so how do I make this more generic?

Comment: You want to turn `N_BBP_c_46137_n` into `BBP` as in the question? Matching a pattern like `N_BBP_*` should give `BBP`?

Answer (score 1):

To turn `N_BBP_c_46137_n` into `BBP` and according to the comment *just want that entire long name such as N_BBP_* to be replaced by only BBP* you might also use a capture group to keep BBP.

```
\bN_(BBP)_\S*
```

- `\bN_` Match N preceded by a word boundary
- `(BBP)` Capture group 1, match `BBP` (or use `[A-Z]+` to match 1+ uppercase chars)
- `_\S*` Match `_` followed by 0+ times a non whitespace char

In the replacement use the first capturing group `$1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HYuWMi/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(N_)[^_]*(_c_\d+_n)
```

Replace with `${1}some new value$2`.

**Details**

- `(N_)`  - Group 1 (`$1` or `${1}` if the next char is a digit): `N_`
- `[^_]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `_`
  -`(_c_\d+_n)` - Group 2 (`$2`): `_c_`, 1 or more digits and then `_n`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XS2uRX/1).